# Angular and $q: strangely, nothing is working at all

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen an example in a website about how to use $q, and tried to paste it to a test project, and change it a little.

The functionality I'm trying to achieve, is to press a button, retrieve a JSON file I have in the root directory, and when the premise succeeds, show the JSON content in a ng-repeat directive.

This is my service, which uses promises in $q:

```
app.factory('dataService', ["$http", "$q", function($http, $q) {
    return {
        getAll: getAll
    }

    function getAll() {
        var defered = $q.defer();
        var promise = defered.promise;

        $http.get('data.json')
            .success(function(data) {
                defered.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(err) {
                defered.reject(err)
            });

        return promise;
    }
}
```

});

This is the HTML. Strangely, my ng-show directive isn't working at all; the span keeps showing the Angular expression as if Angular wasn't imported at all:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="miApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="mainmodule.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="Controller1">
    <button ng-click="receive()">Import data</button>
      <span ng-show="dataArrived" ng-repeat="user in users">- Name: {{user.name}}, Age: {{user.age}}, Job: {{user.job}}</span>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And finally, my controller:

```
app.controller('Controller1', ["$scope", "dataService",
    function($scope, dataService) {

        $scope.dataArrived = false;
        $scope.receive(function() {

            dataService.getAll().then(function(data) {
                $scope.users = data;
                $scope.dataArrived = true;
            }).catch(function(err)) {
                alert("Error: " + err);
            }
        });

    }
]);
```

I don't know what's happening at all. Angular seems to be broken as hell for me: it doesn't show any error on console (been like this all day, I'm seriously hating this platform), it doesn't evaluate the expressions, directives just won't work, etc.

I guess that some part of my code is breaking it all, but then it should show a damn error message, so maybe I'm just having some design problem. Can anybody find what's going wrong?

Comment: `ng-app="miApp">`  Is there any chance your code starts with `angular.module('myApp')` (instead of `('miApp')`?)

Comment: Clever one, but no, I'm using "miApp" (I'm spanish, so "mi" is like "my").

Comment: It was worth a shot :)  Generally speaking "angular isn't doing anything, not even throwing errors" means it's installed (otherwise you get "undefined variable 'angular'" type errors) but not configured correctly (such as looking for an `ng-app` that doesn't exist or with the wrong name).  (You are defining the variable  `'app'` somewhere, right? `var app = angular.module('miApp')` etc?)

Comment: The problem is lots and lots of uncorrected bugs in the code.

Comment: That problem is fixed! As I said, it was a "}" breaking it all. Now I've got another problem, check it out.

Comment: wow please don't rewrite a question into a totally different question, it makes previous answers/comments confusing and useless

Comment: You're right Daniel, but I can't open a new question until 2 hours, and I have to hurry up learning Angular. I'm sorry for that; gotta erase this question when everything's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loads of bugs in the old code. Here's a fixed plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/NN0eXFg87Ys2E3jjYQSu?p=preview

The problem mostly was that you didn't assign your `receive` function properly to the scope. It must be done like so:

```
 $scope.receive = function() {
```

Your code was like

```
 $scope.receive(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a closing div tag with no opening tag, so that could be messing up your html

Comment: Fixed too. I don't really know how the previous div was deleted.